# Sublime text 3 ctrl+click to its default behavior

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

The default behavior of this shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> is to create multiple cursors, but in my case, it was behaving like `goto_definition` command, and then I opened mousemap file I saw that the command is set to `goto_definition`:

```
{
    "button": "button1", 
    "count": 1, 
    "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
    "press_command": "drag_select",
    "command": "goto_definition"
}
```

And I don't know how? Can anyone tell me how to change it to as it usually be?

Comment: Is the mousemap, which defines the binding, in your User directory?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows,  and yes, it is the mousemap which defines the binding in user directory

Answer (score 0):

Two things worked for me, first, if completely remove the setting, or second, if I replace the setting by this setting:

```
{
    "button": "button1", "count": 2,
    "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
    "press_command": "drag_select_callback",
    "press_args": {"by": "words"}
}
```